# using forEach to add an array's elements including nested objects into a new object as keys, but object looks like [Object object]

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a toy problem called isSubsetOf for my bootcamp, which takes an array of strings, numbers, arrays, and/or arrays containing objects. 
It is then used as a method on an existing array, and it returns a boolean suggesting whether 'this' array is a subset of (contained within) input array.

For example:

```
[1, 2, ['hi', {'yo': 'greeting'}] ].isSubSetOf( [1, 2, ['hi', {'yo': 'greeting'}] ] ) // true;

[1, 4].isSubSetOf( [1, 2, 3] ) // false;
```

I currently can successfully return the correct boolean in all cases except for when dealing with an object nested within an array, nested within the input array. When dealing with objects, I am not able to correctly access its key and value. I can only get a [Object, object] when logging it. This means that if all values in the subset array match the index except an object value, I'll still return true.

Here's how I've been coding the solution:

```
Array.prototype.isSubsetOf = function (arr) {

  let obj = {}

  arr.forEach((element) =>  obj[element] = 1); 
  // all elements should be mapped into obj as strings

  console.log('Our object, obj: ', obj);

  return this.reduce( (t, ele) => !obj[ele] ? false : t, true);
  // return false if element from 'this' is not present in obj, else returns t, which defaults to true as 2nd arg of reduce

};
```

Here is the test that should return false, but returns true because the object isn't parsed:

```
let context = [ 'fox', 'dog', 'cow', ['sup', {'yo':'greeting'}] ]
let input = [ 'dog', 'cow', 'fox', ['sup', {'hello':'greeting'}] ]

console.log('Result: ', context.isSubsetOf(input));
```

I expected for the nested object to be console logged as the stringified [key:value], however:

If I check the console log of the object obj, between the forEach and reduce, the nested object is logged as [Object object]. This obj has non duplicate stringed versions of the input array's elements.

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I expect for my function to return true if the context array that the function is being used as a method on is actually a subset of the input array it takes in. It currently returns true even if not a subset, because of an issue within my forEach and how it maps nested objects from the input array into my helper obj variable.

Comment: so you have to make it recursive, and recall itself when an `element` is an array

Comment: Noted, I'll re-implement that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're casting each element to a string then it should come as no surprise that objects are being displayed as `[object Object]`. A quick fix would be to instead call `JSON.stringify` on each of the elements instead of implicitly calling `.toString()`. This will preserve the string value of objects as intended, though you should take care to ensure that the keys and values are in the correct order.

The code for this is below, but I do agree with the comments that recommend a DIY recursive solution, as this would more efficient and extensible if you predicted needing to adapt this to other tasks.

```
Array.prototype.isSubsetOf = function (arr) {
  let obj = {}
  arr.forEach((element) =>  obj[JSON.stringify(element)] = 1); 
  // all elements should be mapped into obj as JSON strings
  console.log('Our object, obj: ', obj);
  return this.reduce( (t, ele) => !obj[JSON.stringify(ele)] ? false : t, true);
  // return false if element from 'this' is not present in obj, else returns t, which defaults to true as 2nd arg of reduce
};
```

As an addendum, if you want objects to be evaluated order-agnostically, you could probably use something like `JSON.stringify(Object.entries(eleOrElement).sort())`, although this would increase time complexity significantly.